# Delete return rows fron select statment using userdefined variable (AS) in where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, having-clause

I have this mysql query

```
select 
  id,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(`placedate`) as placedate_mysqldate  
from 
  orders  HAVING placedate_mysqldate  < '2011-08-01 00:00:00'
```

so the query returns about 1000 record and I want to delete it in the same query statement.

Because the `placedate_mysqldate` is userdefined and not exists in the database I cannot use the normal delete statement like

```
delete * from orders where placedate_mysql < '2011-08-01 00:00:00'
```

so any idea how to do that?

Comment: Yes I notice That and I remove the HAVING thanks. the query is (delete from orders where FROM_UNIXTIME(placedate) < '2011-08-01 00:00:00')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after msarchet gave me an idea the sql query was

```
delete from orders where FROM_UNIXTIME(placedate) < '2011-08-01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete * From orders 
  Where id in (select 
    id
  from 
    orders  HAVING FROM_UNIXTIME(`placedate`)  < '2011-08-01 00:00:00')
```

Delete where the ID is in the result set that you just queried.

Comment: if I do
    delete from orders 
  where id in (select 
    id
  from 
    orders  where FROM_UNIXTIME(`placedate`)  < '2011-08-01 00:00:00')
I Got
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'orders' for update in FROM clause

Comment: you gave me the idea msarchet , the query is (delete from orders where FROM_UNIXTIME(`placedate`)  < '2011-08-01 00:00:00')